# Send a variable to javascript function from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery mouseover event which succesfully calls a javascript function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.nw').mouseover(run_nw);
});

function run_nw() {
...
}
```

However, when I try to pass parameters, the js fails.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.nw').mouseover(run_nw(1));
});

var a;
function run_nw(a) {
...
}
```

Tried looking through SO and through jQ documentation but I'm still stumped. I'm assuming this is a simple formatting issue.

Thanks

(Here is the full code if it helps)

```
    <script>
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    var incr = 650;

        function run_nw() {
            //move x and y
            var topAdjust = -incr;
            var leftAdjust = -incr;

            var top = parseInt($(this).css('top'))+topAdjust;
            var left = parseInt($(this).parent().css('left'))+leftAdjust;

            //rotate
            var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
            var rotate = -randomnumber*10;

            $(this).animate({
                top:top,
                left:left,
                'rotate':rotate
            }, 700, 'swing');
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.nw').mouseover(run_nw);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: One small bug: when using `parseInt` you should pass the number 10 as a second parameter. If you don't, then funky things can happen. If you're number starts with a zero, for example, I think JS interprets it as hex and uses base 16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the function call in an anonymous function:

```
$('.nw').mouseover(function() {
    run_nw(1);
});
```

The way you have it currently will execute the function and pass the *result* of that as the callback to `mouseover`.

**Update**

The problem with your current code is that in the event handler function, `this` does not refer to what you're expecting (it refers to the Window, because you are calling the function from an anonymous callback to `mouseover` - `this` inside the anonymous callback is what you want it to be).

So, you need to pass `this` into the function and change any references to `this` to whatever you choose to name that argument:

```
$('.nw').mouseover(function() {
    run_nw(1, this);
});
function run_nw(a, elem) {
    //Now `elem` is what you expected `this` to be
}
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P42M2/11/).

Comment: Thanks James. I tried that and it didn't work, I'm afraid. I even tried this format with just "run_nw()" with no variables in the parameter of the js. It's weird. I thought your solution would have worked.

Comment: Can you post an example on jsfiddle.net? That will make it easier to see where the problem is.

Comment: In your code Firebug warns me like in JSFiddle; elem.ownerDocument is undefined
source file: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js Line: 6766 and in my local server: elem.ownerDocument is undefined
Source file: http://localhost/.../jquery-latest.js
Line: 6566, your problem is not about mouseover...

Comment: I think it has something to do with the "This" being broken.

Comment: @alper, yeah, that's because it refers to a relative path. That's why I took the code down. The jquery works fine because I tested it without the parameter in the function and it worked. Thanks though.

Comment: In this one http://jsfiddle.net/CyMPj/6/ the alert fires but the div doesn't move, so that's why I'm thinking the "this" selector doesn't know what "this" is after the anonymous function.

Comment: This is the right idea, but the original function is just void; it's not made to accept a parameter. The fiddle provided by Alper shows a value being passed and alerted. Not sure why it didn't work when you called it without the parameter.

Comment: Thanks Greg, see previous comment with jsfiddle example. It turns out the solution is indeed correct, I believe it's a disconnect with the "this" selector.

Comment: I ended up separating the "this" part of the javascript into the part that was working, and the variable part into an anonymous function as James suggested. I basically just needed to have four different x and y movements: (+x +y, -x +y, -x -y, +x -y) and was copying the entire function four times before! Thanks everyone for your help.